# Creating two dictionary variables within an iteration with unique names

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe, iteration, naming-conventions

I have two different groups of dataframes.
One is a Panel, which has its `items` represented by stocks.

Here is the code to get the Panel (for reproducibility)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import re



startDate = '2010-01-01'
endDate = '2016-09-07'  
stocks_query = ['AAPL','OPK']


stocks = web.DataReader(stocks_query, data_source='yahoo',
              start=startDate, end=endDate)
stocks = stocks.swapaxes('items','minor_axis')`
```

Leading to an output of :

```
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 1682 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: AAPL to OPK
Major_axis axis: 2010-01-04 00:00:00 to 2016-09-07 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: Open to Adj Close
```

A single dataframe of the panel looks like this

```
stocks['OPK']

            Open  High   Low  Close      Volume  Adj Close  log_return  \
Date                                                                     
2010-01-04  1.80  1.97  1.76   1.95    234500.0       1.95         NaN   
2010-01-05  1.64  1.95  1.64   1.93    135800.0       1.93   -0.010309   
2010-01-06  1.90  1.92  1.77   1.79    546600.0       1.79   -0.075304   
2010-01-07  1.79  1.94  1.76   1.92    138700.0       1.92    0.070110   
2010-01-08  1.92  1.94  1.86   1.89     62500.0       1.89   -0.015748
```

I then added a couple of custom columns via this code:

```
    for i in stocks:
    stocks[i]['log_return'] = np.log(stocks[i]['Close']/(stocks[i]['Close'].shift(1)))

    stocks[i]['30_Avg_Vol'] = stocks[i] ['Volume'].rolling(min_periods =15, window=30).mean()
```

Then in order to splice out only the rows where the volume is high, I created a dictionary of dataframes (each key is the stock  and each value is the spliced dataframe) via this code

```
High_volume ={}

for i in stocks.items:  #stocks is a panel, the items are the stocks tickers
    print (i)
    High_volume[i] =stocks[i][stocks[i].Volume  >  1.5* stocks[i]['30_Avg_Vol']]
```

So I have a dictionary of spliced dataframes, which I can access each dataframe via the stocks tickers.

```
High_volume['OPK']
High_volume['AAPL']
```

Now for each date( the index is an datetime object) in each row of each of  these `High_volume` dataframes, I want to create a bunch of  mini dataframes.

So for all the dates in  `High_volume['AAPL']` , I want to create a mini_dataframe for each date. For all the dates in`High_volume['OPK']`, I want to create a bunch of mini dataframes. So in this case I want to create two dictionaries which contain mini dataframes.

`High_volume['OPK'] looks something like this, for each date I want to create a mini dataframe`

```
                Open       High        Low      Close      Volume  Adj Close  \
Date                                                                            
2010-02-11   1.710000   2.200000   1.710000   1.940000   2212300.0   1.940000   
2010-02-12   1.940000   2.100000   1.940000   2.030000    739500.0   2.030000   
2010-03-19   2.030000   2.050000   1.950000   2.030000    611800.0   2.030000   
2010-04-12   2.060000   2.210000   2.040000   2.160000    647100.0   2.160000   
2010-04-13   2.210000   2.450000   2.160000   2.320000    823200.0   2.320000
```

Each of the mini dataframes will have about `X` days worth of info. The start date being the row spliced, the end date about `X` days later.  To get the data for`X` other days, I'm splicing the original panel (`stocks`) which has all the stock data.

However, since I'm dealing with many stocks, I will have to create many dictionaries in one iteration (in these case two, `OPK` and `AAPL`) So I need to dynamically name the dictionaries.

So the function to do this would look something like this

```
def slicing (stock, sliced_data, num_of_days):  
 # stocks = list of stock tickers I'm interesting in exploring
#sliced_data =  the high_volume dict I created
#num_of_days =  this represents the X days (the size of each mini-dataframe)

    time_delta = dt.timedelta(days =num_of_days)
     for i in stock:   # stock name
     vars()['mini_dfs' + i] ={}   #dynamically creating a dictionary for that stock
        print (vars()['mini_dfs' + i])  # to make sure dictionary was created
        for date in sliced_data[i].index:   #taking each date of High_volume df
            start_date = date
            end_date = date + time_delta
            vars()['mini_dfs' + i][date] =stocks[i].loc[start_date:end_date] # 
#filling the empty dictionary with dataframes (dates are keys, values are dataframes)

       return    vars()['mini_dfs' + i]  #returning the dictionary before creating the new dictionary
```

The function seems to be executing properly as I'm getting an output of a bunch of mini_dataframes for both stocks. However, it's not being saved to two variables.
It's all being saved to one variable. 
Remember in this case, I'm dealing with two stocks, so I want two dictionaries to be created.

```
x=slicing(['AAPL','OPK'], High_volume , 1)   # This works
```

However,

```
 x,y =slicing(['AAPL','OPK'], High_volume  , 1)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

How can I get the function to output two dictionaries in this case (or one dictionary for each stock, I will wish it analyze)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `return` gives you just one value -- the last dictionary that's created. You can use `yield` to generate a succession of dictionaries like this:

```
def slicing(stock, sliced_data, num_of_days):  
    time_delta = dt.timedelta(days =num_of_days)
    for i in stock:   # stock name
        vars()['mini_dfs' + i] = {}
        for date in sliced_data[i].index: 
            start_date = date
            end_date = date + time_delta
            vars()['mini_dfs' + i][date] = stocks[i].loc[start_date:end_date]
        yield vars()['mini_dfs' + i]
```

And then you can have a list of those dictionaries like this:

```
my_list = [i for i in slicing(['AAPL','OPK'], High_volume, 1)]
```

Comment: Ah! I didnt know that about `return`. I'm going to play around with yield and see if I run into any problems. Thank you.

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you.

Comment: Seems to work. Thank you so much. I will have to read about `yield` now.

Comment: You're very welcome. It's one that's definitely worth learning about.